# i want to fetch a data based on the previous field data i inserted in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-api

when i click on the dropdwon menu of fixtures i get list of fixtures then i choose a fixture then on the next field after I select that there is a team id field in that field i want to choose between the teams i chose in the fixtures field then there is a players id field and in this field i want players to be listed in a dropdown with the specific team id i chose before on the team id
here is my controller:-

`class LineupController extends AppBaseController
{

```
public function index(LineupDataTable $lineupDataTable)
{
    return $lineupDataTable->render('lineups.index');
}

public function create()
{
    $fixtures = $this->getFormattedFixtures();

    $teams = Team::pluck('team_name', 'id')->map(function ($item) {
        return $item['english'].'('.$item['amharic'].')';
    });
    $players = Player::pluck('display_name', 'id')->map(function( $item) {
        return $item['english'].'('.$item['amharic'].')';
    });
    return view('lineups.create', compact('fixtures', 'teams','players'));
}

public function getFormattedFixtures()
{
    return Fixture::with('localTeam', 'visitorTeam')->get()->map(function ($fixture) {
        $fixture->fixture_name = $fixture->localTeam->team_name['english'].' Vs '.$fixture->visitorTeam->team_name['english'].' ('.$fixture->starting_at->toFormattedDateString().')';

        return $fixture;
    })->pluck('fixture_name', 'id');
}
```

}`
and here is my blade fields:-

```
<!-- Fixture Id Field -->
`<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        {!! Form::label('fixture_id', 'Fixture:', ['class' => 'col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-12 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-12">
            {!! Form::select('fixture_id', $fixtures, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Fixture']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

<!-- Team Id Field -->
`<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        {!! Form::label('team_id', 'Team:', ['class' => 'col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-12 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-12">
            {!! Form::select('team_id', [], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Team']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

<!-- Player Id Field -->
`<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        {!! Form::label('player_id', 'Player:', ['class' => 'col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-12 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-12">
            {!! Form::select('player_id', [], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Player']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

it only fetches the fixtures then when i click on the team id there is no data